# Is it possible to get the average time between a range of timestamps in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have an events table that store an event name and time with the owner (device_id). I want to know the average time of which an event happens.

I know Cassandra support AVG() but I'm sure it wasn't designed for this use-case.

I played around with counters but the fact that they are not consistent and can only be used inside a table with no other fields make it hard to implement properly and would create a mess.

Simple events table:

```
CREATE TABLE tests.events(
  device_id TEXT,
  event_name TEXT,
  event_time TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(device_id, event_name)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time DESC)
WITH default_time_to_live = 2592000; // 30 days
```

My current query:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE device_id = "abcd" AND event_time >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00+0200' AND event_time <= '2019-01-02 00:00:00+0200' LIMIT 100 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

I retrieve the last 100 events from a device. Is it possible, directly in Cassandra, to return the average time between events?

Let's say I have the following event_time:

```
2019-01-01 10:00:00
2019-01-01 11:00:00
2019-01-01 11:30:00
```

The average would be 45 (minutes).

I'm planning on eventually rely on some sort of machine learning code in which I can feed it events after a grace period, but I'm nowhere near that point yet so I'm looking for a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use user-defined aggregate functions, like [described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html). I think that you can almost re-use the function that is shown there, only change the code for state initialization. You'll need to change the `enable_user_defined_functions` to true in your `cassandra.yaml` file.

To get good performance, you'll need to make sure that that aggregations are executed only inside single partition.  You can look into [this blog post](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2015) for more examples & best practices.